# Combine sublists of nested list when the first two list elements are equal

Tags: list-manipulation

New to Mathematica, I have a nested list with the following structure:

```
{ {A,B,C,D,E,F},{a,b,c,d,e,f},{G,H,I,J,K,L},.......}
```

All sublists are of equal length. I want to combine these sublists such that when A=a and B=b, the third list element C is replaced with the mean of C and c, element D is replaced with the mean of D and d, and so on through the last element of the sublists. The completed list would have the following form:

```
{{A,B,Mean[C,c],Mean[D,d],Mean[E,e],Mean[F,f]},....}
```

Thanks.

Comment: When two sublists match their first 2 elements, they're replaced 1 sublist with mean values, but what's the result when the first 2 elements of the sublists elements **don't match**, that is, `A ≠ a` or `B ≠ b`? Maybe the sublists are removed from the nested list?

Comment: Hi @creidhne when the two sublists don't match, I just want to leave the sublists as they are i.e. `{{A,B,C,D,E,F},{G,H,I,J,K,L}} `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to MMA and MMA SE! There are many ways to do this. Here's a "straightforward" way, where it's easy to keep track of what happens when. The procedure we'll follow is

1. Group all lists which start with the same two elements into lists of those lists.
2. Act on each group of lists to combine them in the way you want.

For the first we'll use `GatherBy` with the function `Take[#, 2] &`. `Take[list, 2]` will produce a list consisting of the first 2 elements, and `GatherBy` will compare these values and put lists with the same value in the same list. See [Rearranging And Restructuring Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RearrangingAndRestructuringLists.html) for more such functions. (Equivalent to `Take[#, 2] &`: `#[[1;;2]] &`, `Extract[{{1},{2}}]`, and more.)

If you haven't seen it, `<expression involving #> &` is syntax for an anonymous function with argument slot `#`. There's another equivalent syntax for anonymous functions, which is `x |-> <expression involving x>`.

```
GatherBy[list, Take[#, 2] &]

(* Example: *)

a = {{3, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 1, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 2},
     {1, 2, 0, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 2, 1, 0}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 1},
     {2, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 2}}

GatherBy[a, Take[#, 2] &]

(* Out: 

{{{3, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 1, 2, 2}, {3, 1, 2, 1, 0}}, {{3, 3, 1, 1, 1}}, 
 {{0, 1, 1, 0, 2}}, {{1, 2, 0, 2, 3}}, {{3, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 2}}, 
 {{0, 0, 2, 0, 1}}, {{2, 2, 0, 0, 2}}}

 *)
```

Here we can use the fact that `Mean[{a, a, a}]` is `a`, and apply `Mean` "across" the whole group of lists: we want to turn a group of the form `{{a1, a2, a3, ...}, {b1, b2, b3, ...}, ...}` into `{Mean[{a1, b1, ...}], Mean[{a2, b2, ...}], ...}`.

So we want to `Map` (`/@`) a function that does this to a single group over the result of `GatherBy`, so as to apply it to each group. The function we want to map is one that first takes the `Transpose` (which is possible since all lists in a group will be the same length) and then applies `Mean` to all the lists that are elements of the resulting list. Applying `Mean` to all the elements is another `Map`. So we want to apply the following function to each group:

```
x |-> Mean /@ Transpose[x]
```

This is the function we want to `Map` over the result of `GatherBy`.

Putting it all together, let's define a function which will do this for an arbitrary list (of equal-length lists)

```
combineLists[list_] := (x |-> Mean /@ Transpose[x]) /@ GatherBy[list, Take[#, 2] &]

combineLists[a]

(* Out:

{{3, 1, 1, 1, 2/3}, {3, 3, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 2}, {1, 2, 0, 2, 3},
 {3, 2, 3/2, 2, 5/2}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 1}, {2, 2, 0, 0, 2}}
```

---

For familiarity with Mathematica:  "threading across lists" like we do with `Mean` is actually a very common operation—so common that there's a built-in called `MapThread` to do something similar. For a function `f`, `MapThread[f, {{a1, a2, a3, ...}, {b1, b2, b3, ...}, ...}]` produces `{f[a1, b1, ...], f[a2, b2, ...], ...}`. Note that `Mean`, however, takes in a single list as an argument, not several different arguments. So instead of `f[a1, b1, ...]` we want `Mean[{a1, b1, ...}]`. There are two ways of still using `MapThread`, though!

1: When defining anonymous functions, `#` stands for the first argument. `#2`, `#3`, etc. stand for the next argument. (`#1` is valid too, and is equivalent to `#`.) But what if we want to include the whole sequence of arguments, no matter how long it is? Then we use `##`, and that stands for a whole `Sequence`. So here we can actually just use `MapThread[Mean[{##}] &, group]`. Also, `MapThread` has what's called an "operator form" which is common in Mathematica: `MapThread[f]` is a function that can be applied to a list, so `MapThread[f][list]` is the same as `MapThread[f, list]`. So we can just map `MapThread[Mean[{##}] &]`:

```
(* Equivalent definition *)

combineLists[list_] := MapThread[Mean[{##}] &] /@ GatherBy[list, Take[#, 2] &]
```

2: When we write `{a,b,c}` we're using syntactic sugar—it's not what's "really going on". The actual expression can be seen with `FullForm`, which is **an incredibly useful tool in Mathematica**, as it lets you see all the information you need. `{a,b,c}` is actually `List[a, b, c]`. `List` may as well be a function; in general, that part of the expression is called a *head*. (`Head[{a,b,c}]` gives `List`.) Note that, as in actual math, the function `f[g[x, y, ...]]` is the composition of `f` and `g`. So too in Mathematica; composition is denoted by `@*`. And what is `Mean[{a,b,...}]` but `Mean[List[a,b,...]]`? So we can instead simply use `MapThread[Mean @* List]` in our definition:

```
(* Equivalent definition *)

combineLists[list_] := MapThread[Mean @* List] /@ GatherBy[list, Take[#, 2] &]
```

---

Finally, as pointed out by @kglr, we can simply use `Mean[group]` instead of e.g. `Mean /@ Transpose[group]`! This is because `Mean` averages the elements of the group as vectors, and averaging on vectors works componentwise! As another note on how Mathematica handles operations on lists, some symbols like `Plus` have the attribute `Listable`. (Evaluate `Attributes[Plus]` to see `Listable` along with a whole lot of others. In general, attributes affect the way a function is both evaluated and pattern-matched in special, built-in ways.) This means that the `Plus` operation is threaded over any lists appearing in its argument: `1 + {a,b,c}` is `{1 + a, 1+ b, 1+ c}`, `{a,b,c} + {x,y,z}` is `{a x, b y, c z}`, etc. ("Threading" can be done manually—and over different heads than `List`!—with the function `Thread`.) All basic numeric functions are `Listable`, such as `Times`, `Power`, etc. (You can make your own function `Listable` with e.g. `SetAttributes[f, Listable]`.) In any case, I hope the explanation using `Transpose` and `MapThread` was still informative! :)

Comment: `Mean[{{a,b,c},{x,y,z},{u,v,w}}]` gives the same result `as Mean/@Transpose[{{a,b,c},{x,y,z}, {u,v,w}}]`. So we can use `Mean/@GatherBy[list, Take[#, 2] &]` (no need for `MapThread` or `Transpose`).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! This resolved everything perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

A 10X5 matrix as an example input:

```
SeedRandom[1];
lists = RandomInteger[3, {10, 5}];

MatrixForm @ lists
```

[image]

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) + [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) + [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) as follows:

```
Values @ GroupBy[lists, #[[{1, 2}]] &, Mean]
```

> ```
> {{3, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1/3, 4/3, 5/3}, {0, 1, 5/2, 3/2, 0}, 
>  {3, 3, 5/2, 2, 3/2}, {2, 0, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 3}}
> ```

```
MatrixForm @ %
```

[image]

We can generalize this into a function that takes a list of lists, a list of column indices to group by, and a function (that returns a list with length equal to number of columns in the input matrix) to apply to groups. The third argument is optional with default value `Mean`.

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1[lst_, parts_, func_ : Mean] := KeyValueMap[ReplacePart[#2, Thread[parts -> #]] &]@
  GroupBy[lst, #[[parts]] &,  func]
```

***Examples:***

```
cols = {1, 2};
Row[Pane[MatrixForm @ #, BaselinePosition -> Top] & /@ 
  {lists, MatrixForm[Values@GroupBy[lists, #[[cols]] &, MatrixForm]], 
   f1[lists, cols]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

With `cols = {2, 5}` we get

[image]

Highlight keys and groups:

```
ClearAll[highlightByKeys]
highlightByKeys[keys_] := Module[
   {styl = AssociationThread[#, ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@#]] & @
      DeleteDuplicates[#[[All, keys]]]}, 
   Map[(x |-> Map[Highlighted[#, Background -> styl[x[[keys]]]] &, 
        MapAt[Style[#, 18, Bold] &, x, List /@ keys]])] @ #] &
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[Pane[Labeled[MatrixForm@#, #2, Top], 
    BaselinePosition -> Top] & @@@ 
  {{highlightByKeys[cols]@lists, "lists"}, 
   {highlightByKeys[cols]@f1[lists, cols], "mean"}, 
   {highlightByKeys[cols]@f1[lists, cols, Total], "total"}, 
   {highlightByKeys[cols]@f1[lists, cols, Max /@ Transpose[#] &], "max"}, 
   {highlightByKeys[cols]@f1[lists, cols, First], "first"}}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

With `cols = {2, 5}` we get

[image]

With `cols = {3}` we get

[image]

With `cols = {1, 4, 5}` we get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assume that sublists are paired, and that the result should have no sublist when two paired sublists don't match their first 2 elements. The reasoning for removing unmatched sublist pairs is that they'd be indistinguishable from pairs that match.

Make a sample list and set the second pair of sublists so that the first 2 elements don't match.

```
SeedRandom[123];
n = 4;
pairedList = Flatten[Table[{Join[#, RandomInteger[10, n]], 
  Join[#, RandomInteger[10, n]]}&@RandomInteger[10, 2],{4}], 1];
pairedList[[3, 1]] = 1;
TableForm[Partition[pairedList, 2], TableDepth -> 2]
```

> `{7, 4, 10, 10, 0, 2}  {7, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8}`
> `{1, 9, 8, 10, 5, 2}   {3, 9, 10, 6, 2, 6}`
> `{2, 0, 4, 1, 7, 6}    {2, 0, 8, 3, 6, 6}`
> `{4, 10, 6, 5, 3, 5}   {4, 10, 7, 5, 3, 7}`

Check each pair of sublists. If the first 2 elements match, replace them with a list with means, otherwise remove the two sublists from the output. With the sample nested list, we removed the second two sublists, and there are three lists with means in the result.

```
Table[If[
    Take[pairs[[1]], 2] == Take[pairs[[2]], 2],
    Join[Take[#1, 2], N@Mean[{Drop[#1, 2], Drop[#2, 2]}]] &@@ pairs,
    Nothing],
  {pairs, Partition[pairedList, 2]}]
```

> `{{7, 4, 8., 8.5, 4.5, 5.}, {2, 0, 6., 2., 6.5, 6.}, {4, 10, 6.5, 5., 3., 6.}}`

### Edit reply to comment:

To keep sublists that don't match, we can use:

```
Flatten[
  Table[If[
    Take[pairs[[1]], 2] == Take[pairs[[2]], 2],
    {Join[Take[#1, 2], N@Mean[{Drop[#1, 2], Drop[#2, 2]}]] &@@ pairs},
    Join[pairs]],
  {pairs, Partition[pairedList, 2]}], 1]
```

> `{{7, 4, 8., 8.5, 4.5, 5.}, {1, 9, 8, 10, 5, 2}, {3, 9, 10, 6, 2, 6}, {2, 0, 6., 2., 6.5, 6.}, {4, 10, 6.5, 5., 3., 6.}}`

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the same point as @creidhne:

```
t = Partition[pairedList, 2]
```

> ```
> {{{7, 4, 10, 10, 0, 2}, {7, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8}}, {{1, 9, 8, 10, 5, 2}, {3,
>     9, 10, 6, 2, 6}}, {{2, 0, 4, 1, 7, 6}, {2, 0, 8, 3, 6, 6}}, {{4, 
>    10, 6, 5, 3, 5}, {4, 10, 7, 5, 3, 7}}}
> ```

Write a function to check the equality of the first two entries (discarding the pair when necessary), and find the mean of the pair of lists (element-wise). Join sections as needed.

```
f[{m_List, n_List}] := Module[{},
  If[m[[1]] != n[[1]], Return[Nothing]];
  If[m[[2]] != n[[2]], Return[Nothing]];
  Join[m[[1 ;; 2]], Mean /@ Transpose[{m, n}][[3 ;; -1]]]
  ]

Map[f, t, 1] (* f /@ t *)
```

> ```
> {{7, 4, 8, 17/2, 9/2, 5}, {2, 0, 6, 2, 13/2, 6}, {4, 10, 13/2, 5, 3, 
>   6}}
> ```